# For loop error with array of float numbers

Tags: python, pycharm

```
a = [0.30, 0.15, 0.0, 0.25, 0.30, 0.0]
b = []

for i in range(a):
    if a[i] == 0.00:
        b.append(0)
    else:
        b.append(1)
```

What I want is to fill b with 0 and 1 according to if the same index in a is equal to or different from zero.
Why am I getting the following error: "TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"?

Comment: Mandatory warning: Checking for equality for floating-point numbers are most likely wrong due to the imprecision of floating-point numbers. Check with a small epsilon instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) takes only integers (start:stop:step). Not a list. So I think you want to use `len(list)`

```
a = [0.30, 0.15, 0.0, 0.25, 0.30, 0.0]
b = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 0.00:
        b.append(0)
    else:
        b.append(1)
```

Lastly, all this can be done using list comprehension

#Note: when iterating through a list, don't use `range()`

```
b = [i if i == 0.00 else 1 for i in [0.30, 0.15, 0.0, 0.25, 0.30, 0.0]]
```

output

```
[1, 1, 0.0, 1, 1, 0.0]
```

Comment: While it works in this case, there should be a huge warning specifying that checking for equality between floats are often not correct due to imprecision of floating-point numbers.

Comment: That's true. So what would be an alternative @TedKleinBergman?

Comment: You should generally be [checking against a small epsilon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67742409/6486738)

Answer (score 3):

The bug has already been covered in the other answers. Here's an alternative implementation:

```
>>> a = [0.30, 0.15, 0.0, 0.25, 0.30, 0.0]
>>> b = [int(bool(x)) for x in a]
>>> b
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, `range` takes an integer, not a list. But since no one is covering the biggest flaw in the code, here's a useful warning:

**Checking for equality between floating-point numbers are most likely wrong due to the imprecision of floating-point numbers!**

As an example, `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` is `False`. Just try it yourself. Instead, check with a small epsilon.

```
EPSILON = 0.0001
a = [0.30, 0.15, 0.0, 0.25, 0.30, 0.0]
b = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    if -EPSILON <= a[i] && a[i] <= EPSILON:
        b.append(0)
    else:
        b.append(1)
```

Or use a list comprehension, or any other technique used in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as @BuddyBob said, `range` takes an integer, so that way won't work. Second, I am assuming that you want to loop through the items in `a`, so it would be easier to use `for i in a:` like this.

```
a = [0.30, 0.15, 0.0, 0.25, 0.30, 0.0]
b = []

for i in a:
    if i == 0.00:
        b.append(0)
    else:
        b.append(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `range` in your given example. You can just loop through list items:

```
a = [0.30, 0.15, 0.0, 0.25, 0.30, 0.0]
b = []

for i in a:
    b.append(0 if i == 0 else 1)
```